# Visual Studio 2010 cannot add existing item in C project

Tags: visual-studio

I have the source code and hope to add the file `xxx.c` to `source files` of the project created by Visual Studio 2010. However, the source file is still in the original location even if I right click `add` --->`existing item`. What is added is actually just a link. What is the simpe way to adding the item (but not a link) to the project?

Comment: What does "adding the item to the project" mean to you? If you want it to be copied or moved to a different location on your file system, you should do that before adding it to your project.

Comment: "adding the item to the project" means I right click the `source Files` in VS 2010 and select `add existing item`.

Comment: What do you think MSVS should do when you add the existing item to the project?

Comment: Can the code file automatically move to the project folder if I add `existing item`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the source file into the same folder along with your other source/project files using [Windows Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Explorer). Then use *Add* -> *Existing Item*.